# Laravel 4 Composer not installing Packages

Tags: laravel, composer-php

i want to make a webservice and i need to install a extension called JWT-Auth.

I never really used composer so i have no idea where the problem is.

composer.json -> require:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.4",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
    "illuminate/http": "5.0.*"
}
```

and the output of composer:

```
 $ sudo composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v4.2.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.1
    - illuminate/http v5.0.0 requires illuminate/session 5.0.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4].
    - illuminate/http v5.0.22 requires illuminate/session 5.0.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4].
    - illuminate/http v5.0.25 requires illuminate/session 5.0.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4].
    - illuminate/http v5.0.26 requires illuminate/session 5.0.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4].
    - illuminate/http v5.0.28 requires illuminate/session 5.0.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4].
    - illuminate/http v5.0.33 requires illuminate/session 5.0.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4].
    - illuminate/http v5.0.4 requires illuminate/session 5.0.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4].
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - Installation request for illuminate/http 5.0.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4].

 $
```

Comment: can you provide us your require-dev{ } snippts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 4.2 needs 0.4.* of the jwt-auth package. And you should'nt need to define illuminate/http, Laravel will do that for you.

Try this (not tested):

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.4",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.4.*"   
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Worked perfectly, so simple but so effective. :D

Comment: Glad it worked, please upvote and mark as best answer :)